# RunKeeper fails to pick up my heart rate

Tags: heart-rate-monitor, polar-wearlink, app

I bought the "Polar WearLink hert rate sensor with Bluetooth" in order to monitor my heart rate when running.

I paired it successfully with my Android.

But Runkeeper doesn't show a heart rate, although it should according [to the instructions](http://runkeeper.com/heart-rate-monitoring)

What can I do to fix it? What can I do to check if the sensor/transmitter is actually working?

Comment: Maybe this is better as a question in the chat..

Comment: @FredrikD Why? Any information missing?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized to one person/situation.

Comment: @JohnP I disagree, this problem is likely to occur to other people. Equipment questions are on topic.

Comment: Don't think so. If I'm without heart rate for two days, a visit to the doctor will be dangerous ... for the doctor.

Comment: @JensSchauder I've had problems with this model in the past as well, trying to troubleshoot it is a nightmare, because you're basically shooting in the dark. The Polar Wearlink gives no feedback in whatever mode it is in and even if its pared with your phone, Runkeeper offers no feedback as to whether it actually picked it up (unlike an app like Sportstracker). So its an overall subpar experience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried it again and now it works. I have no real idea why it works today, but didn't yesterday, but I'll describe what I did as precise as possible, so others might get some useful information out of it:

**Yesterday (didn't work)**

Activated Bluetooth on smartphone Put transmitter on strap, put strap around chest. Paired transmitter with phone. I'm not sure when I started Runkeeper ... it is kind of hard to tell if an application is running or not anyway.

**Today (did work)**
Made the rubber part of the strap wet. Although hardly any water stayed on it, and yesterday I was heavily sweating at least a couple of minutes after I started the process, so everything should have been nicely wet. Put strap around chest. Put transmitter on Started Bluetooth. Started Runkeeper.

It seems that the heart rate sensor/transmitter has some kind of sleep mode and needs to wake up, since it does not have any kind of external switch. Maybe because the strap was dray first and only slowly got moistened there wasn't a sudden enough change for it to get started ...

I'll accept another answer if it provides something more specific, especially a way to debug this kind of issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the entire rubber area is moist enough right before you put the strap on. It should work immediately.